# Postgres - connection timeout

Tags: pythonanywhere

When I trying connect to my postgres database, I always receiving connection time out error. For instance I want to connect from pqadmin. Can you please help with it ?

Comment: There are too many reasons for that, can you try and run `pgadmin` on the same server Posgress is running on?

Comment: I think no. But my postgres works via pythonanywhere postgres concole

Comment: So it's working from your machine through Python but not using `pgadmin` or it's a different machine?

Comment: Seems that probrem is resolved. Thanks @Yaron for your support !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL databases on PythonAnywhere are protected by a firewall, so external computers can't access them directly -- you need to use a thing called an SSH tunnel, which opens a secure SSH connection to PythonAnywhere, then sends the Postgres stuff over it.

[This help page on the PythonAnywhere site has the details on how to set that up.](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingPostgresFromOutsidePythonAnywhere)